# Type annotation for converting nullability

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I would like to have a function that can remove the nullability of a value (throwing an exception if the value is actually null), but I can't seem to get the type annotations correct.  My first attempt was:

```js
/**
 * @param {?T} obj
 * @param {string} message
 * @return {!T}
 * @template T
 */
function checkNotNull(obj, message) {
  if (obj === null) {
    throw message;
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, though.  If I use it like `foo(checkNotNull(someVar))` (where `foo()` expects a non-nullable parameter), I still get the `TYPE_MISMATCH` error (basically saying that the parameter is still marked as nullable).

Is there a way to actually do this?  Or do I need to keep typing in the manual null-checks followed by explicit type hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in the current implementations.  There are several changes in planned to allow this but nothing immanent.